# What's the distance that let me hide my super jumps using Stealth Jump?

Tags: splatoon-3

From [Stealth Jump](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Stealth_Jump) official wikia, in Splatoon 2 section, we have:

> Stealth Jump hides the user's Super Jump landing marker, except for players who are **within a certain distance** to it; (as a result, the only players who are able to see the landing marker are those who are **close enough** to it). For players within a **certain range of distance** to that landing marker, the transparency of that landing marker is increased as the distance from the player to it increases.

But what exactly is this "certain distance"?
Apparently, in Splatoon 2 they made an unusual reference to [Inkblot Art Academy](https://cdn.wikimg.net/en/splatoonwiki/images/thumb/8/85/S2_Inkblot_Art_Academy_Overview.jpg/1200px-S2_Inkblot_Art_Academy_Overview.jpg) map, which is "about 3 tiles in the center area".

If the statement is correct, is this still true for Splatoon 3?